Physical interpretation of the Green's function approach to Laplace equation
Consider the Laplace equation in a region $D$ with boundary $\partial D$,
$$
\nabla^2 u = 0, \qquad u|_{\partial D} = \varphi \ .
$$

In terms of electrostatic field, we are computing the interior potential by knowing the boundary potential; the boundary potential will create some physical surface charge density $\rho_0(\mathbf{r}')$ at $\mathbf{r}' \in \partial D$.

The Green's function approach first constructs $G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}_0)$ such that
$$
\nabla^2_\mathbf{r} G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}_0) = - \delta(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_0), \qquad
G(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}_0)|_{\mathbf{r} \in \partial D} = 0 \ .
$$
The final solution will be
$$
u(\mathbf{r} \in D) = - \int_{\partial D} \varphi(\mathbf{r}') \frac{\partial G(\mathbf{r}', \mathbf{r})}{\partial n'} d\sigma' \ .
$$
Here, $\mathbf{r}' \in \partial D$ is the integration variable, $d\sigma'$ denotes the area element of $\partial D$.
I am struggling to understand the physics in the result. Assume $u$ to be the electric potential.
The $G(\mathbf{r}', \mathbf{r})$ is simply the electric potential at $\mathbf{r}' \in \partial D$ from a point charge sitting at $\mathbf{r}$ (surrounded by grounded conductor at $\partial D$, carrying some induced surface charges). The derivative $\partial G(\mathbf{r}', \mathbf{r})/\partial n'$ computes the corresponding normal electric field, propotional to the induced surface charge density $\rho_\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{r}')$. So the potential roughly is
$$
- \int_{\partial D} \varphi(\mathbf{r}')\rho_\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{r}')d\sigma' \ .
$$
This looks weird: why is the interior potential be $\sim$ boundary potential $\times$ induced charge density?
As pointed out in a comment in a related question link, Jackson has some discussions pointing out that the surface term should be interpreted as from a dipole layer $D = - \epsilon_0 u$. Where is this dipole layer from?

I will set $\epsilon_0 = 1$ in the following. Recall that to solve the Poisson equation using Green's functions, you compute:
$$
u(x) = \int G(x,y)\rho(y)d^3y
$$
Staring hard at Kirchhoff integral formula, you recognise the same structure:
$$
\begin{align}
u(x) &= -\oint \phi(y) \nabla_yG(y,x)\cdot d^2y \\
&= -\oint \nabla_yG(x,y)\cdot \phi(y)d^2y
\end{align}
$$
The key insight is to use the symmetry of the Green's function:
$$
G(x,y) = G(y,x)
$$
This follows from the fact that the Laplacian is symmetric and the Green's function is its inverse. You therefore identify the dipole layer of surface moment density:
$$
D = -\phi
$$
along the normal direction (pointing outward). This follows from the normal derivative:
$$
u(x) =\lim_{h\to0}\oint [G(x,y-hn)\phi(y)-G(x,y)\phi(y)]d^2y
$$
so it is indeed the field generated by two oppositely charged surface scaled to result in the dipole layer announced by Jackson.
Alternatively, this follows from the interface conditions in electrostatics. Crossing at $x$ a charged surface of normal $n$ and density $\sigma$, you observe a discontinuity in the electric field $E$:
$$
E(x+0^+n)-E(x+0^-n) = \sigma(x) n(x)
$$
Taking the derivative along the normal direction, you get a similar result when the surface has a normal surface polarisation of density $D$:
$$
V(x+0^+n)-V(x+0^-n) = D(x)
$$
For your original Dirichlet problem, you can extend the domain to the entire space so that $u(x\notin D) = 0$. You therefore have a discontinuity of $u$ at $\partial D$, which must be caused by the dipole layer given by Jackson's formula.
Finally, a with the benefit of hindsight, you can notice that it just follows from dimensional analysis. If $\phi$ quantifies a local electric charge moment density, it can only be dipolar by unit considerations.
